# How to run tests contingent on machine endianness?

Tags: java, junit

Some tests i have only make sense on a `LITTLE_ENDIAN` machine.

Can this be done cleaner then in

```
@Test
public void testSomething(){
   if (ByteOrder.nativeOrder() == ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN) {
      // do your thing
   } else {
      // skip
   }
}
```

I'd like to avoid this check in each and every test, if possible.

Comment: You could use `@Category` to group your tests by endianness and then run the appropriate category.

Comment: @Aurand Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do this:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue( ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN.equals( ByteOrder.nativeOrder() );
    // more code
}
```

JUnit assumptions are:

> A set of methods useful for stating assumptions about the conditions
>   in which a test is meaningful. A failed assumption does not mean the
>   code is broken, but that the test provides no useful information.

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html

It seems like what you are trying to do is *state the conditions in which your test is meaningful*.